# Group by multiple columns and tag unique sub-groups

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Starting with this data:

```
+--------+------------+--------+--------+
| Fruit  | Vegetables | Colors | Number |
+--------+------------+--------+--------+
| Apple  | Beans      | Blue   |     10 |
| Apple  | Beans      | Blue   |     10 |
| Apple  | Beans      | Blue   |     20 |
| Apple  | Beans      | Blue   |     20 |
| Apple  | Beans      | Green  |     20 |
| Apple  | Beans      | Green  |     20 |
| Banana | Brocoli    | Red    |     10 |
| Banana | Brocoli    | Red    |     10 |
| Banana | Brocoli    | Blue   |     10 |
| Banana | Beans      | Blue   |     20 |
| Banana | Beans      | Green  |     20 |
| Banana | Beans      | Green  |     20 |
+--------+------------+--------+--------+
```

I want to count the unique combinations of Vegetables, Colors, and Numbers BY their Fruit.  So I started with this query.

```
SET @a:=0;

select *, @a:=@a+1 as newid FROM(
select fruit, vegetable, color, number

FROM test

GROUP BY fruit, vegetable, color, number) as info
```

to arrive at this data

```
+-------+--------+------------+--------+--------+
| newid | Fruit  | Vegetables | Colors | Number |
+-------+--------+------------+--------+--------+
|     1 | Apple  | Beans      | Blue   |     10 |
|     2 | Apple  | Beans      | Blue   |     20 |
|     3 | Apple  | Beans      | Green  |     20 |
|     4 | Banana | Brocoli    | Red    |     10 |
|     5 | Banana | Brocoli    | Blue   |     10 |
|     6 | Banana | Beans      | Blue   |     20 |
|     7 | Banana | Beans      | Green  |     20 |
+-------+--------+------------+--------+--------+
```

but my ultimate goal is to get to here

```
+----------+--------+------------+--------+--------+
|    ID    | Fruit  | Vegetables | Colors | Number |
+----------+--------+------------+--------+--------+
| Apple-1  | Apple  | Beans      | Blue   |     10 |
| Apple-1  | Apple  | Beans      | Blue   |     10 |
| Apple-2  | Apple  | Beans      | Blue   |     20 |
| Apple-2  | Apple  | Beans      | Blue   |     20 |
| Apple-3  | Apple  | Beans      | Green  |     20 |
| Apple-3  | Apple  | Beans      | Green  |     20 |
| Banana-1 | Banana | Brocoli    | Red    |     10 |
| Banana-1 | Banana | Brocoli    | Red    |     10 |
| Banana-2 | Banana | Brocoli    | Blue   |     10 |
| Banana-3 | Banana | Beans      | Blue   |     20 |
| Banana-4 | Banana | Beans      | Green  |     20 |
| Banana-4 | Banana | Beans      | Green  |     20 |
+----------+--------+------------+--------+--------+
```

I realize that ultimately I can use `group_concat`, but I am not sure how best to the counter to start over, inside the query.

Comment: I appreciate both of your answers, obviously this is stretching what a SQL query is for, and I may consider moving this heavy lifting into a stored proc, but the answers got me to my solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

firstly this will reset the count for you on a different fruit.

```
SELECT *, 
       if(@a = fruit, @b := @b + 1, @b := 1) as counter,
       @a := fruit
FROM (
    select fruit, vegetable, color, number
    FROM test
    GROUP BY fruit, vegetable, color, number
) t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @a := null, @b := null)temp
```

but to provide a result to what you showed for your expected outcome.. try this

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(fruit, ' ', counter) as fruit, vegetable, color, number
FROM
(   SELECT 
        *, 
        if(@a = fruit, if(@c = color AND @d = number, @b, @b := @b + 1), @b := 1) as counter,
        @a := fruit, @c := color, @d := number
    FROM test
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @a := null, @b := null, @c := null, @d := null)temp
)t
```

basically for the second query you do a row by row comparison to see if the values in the previous row are the ones in the next row, if they arent then reset the counter, if they are then dont reset but increment, and if both the color and number match the previous row just put in that counter value and don't increment it

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ce817/1)

they key evaluation you have to make here is to put assignment to the column variables after the conditional check for the counter.. that way you are comparing the previous rows value with the current one... one thing to note is MySQL doesn't guarantee that this order of evaluation will happen this way.. but normally evaluates from left to right.

Comment: @JasonB thanks for the kind words! I hope you understood everything lol.. good luck!!

Comment: Indeed I did, going to save this bit of logic next time I have to do some crazy grouping like this!

Answer (score 2):

You have a good start. You're right about the difficulty with the GROUP BY. You could go that way, but you;d need a JOIN operation back to the original table, to get all of the rows,

Here's another approach that uses a "trick": preserving the values from the current row in user-defined variables, so that these values can be compared to the values of the next row. We use conditional tests to determine whether we leave the counter at its existing value, or we increment it by one, or reset it back to one.

We use an `ORDER BY` clause in the query to ensure rows are returned in the order that the rows need to be compared; we will be comparing each row the the value from the immediately preceding row.

As an example:

```
SELECT CONCAT(r.fruit,'-',r.i) AS ID
     , r.fruit
     , r.vegetable
     , r.color
     , r.number
  FROM ( SELECT IF( t.fruit <=> @fruit
                , IF( t.vegetable <=> @vegetable 
                  AND t.color     <=> @color
                  AND t.number    <=> @number
                  , @i := @i + 0
                  , @i := @i + 1
                  )
                , @i := 1
                ) AS i
              , @fruit     := t.fruit      AS fruit
              , @vegetable := t.vegetable  AS vegetable
              , @color     := t.color      AS color
              , @number    := t.number     AS number
           FROM ( SELECT @i         := 1
                       , @fruit     := NULL
                       , @vegetable := NULL
                       , @color     := NULL
                       , @number    := NULL
                ) i
          CROSS
           JOIN test t
          ORDER 
             BY t.fruit
              , t.vegetable
              , t.color
              , t.number
       ) r
```

The inline view aliased as `i` initializes our user-defined variables (rather than having to rely on separate statements.) We don't really care what that inline view returns, except that it returns 1 row (because we've specified a JOIN operation); what we really care about is that it gets evaluated BEFORE the query that references it runs.

The CROSS JOIN to test gets us all the rows from test.

We specify an ORDER BY clause so that the rows are returned in the specified order. This is important because we are going to be comparing the values in a row to the values from the immediately preceding row.

The "trick" is an expression in that compares the values from the current row (e.g. t.fruit) to the value from the previous row: (e.g. @fruit.) We use a boolean expression that returns TRUE if all the columns match, if that's true, we increment the counter (@i). Otherwise, we reset the counter to 1.

MySQL doesn't *guarantee* the order of evaluation, but we observe that the expressions in the SELECT list are evaluated left-to-right, so we're careful to perform the conditional test BEFORE we overwrite the user-defined variables holding the values from the previous row.

We wrap that whole query in parens and give it an alias, so we can run another outer query to concatenate the generated counter into a string (per the specified result set.)

Some **IMPORTANT NOTES((:

This syntax is specific to MySQL; the behavior we observe is NOT guaranteed, but it's the closest we come to emulating the "analytic functions" available in other databases.

Be aware that this behavior MAY change in a future release of MySQL.

Comment: also +1 from me spencer nice answer :)

Comment: @JasonB: I probably go overboard on the explanation, but I think it's important that someone writing a query like this actually *understand* what its doing. Once MySQL supports analytic functions (like Oracle and SQL Server do) we will be using much different syntax.  (BTW... I should mention that `<=>` is the NULL-safe comparison operator (a MySQL extension) which returns either TRUE or FALSE (it never returns NULL; in comparing, it considers NULL to be distinct value, `NULL<=>NULL` is TRUE, `'a'<=>NULL` is FALSE.

Comment: @spencer7593, Your explanation was great, I appreciate you explaining the subtle behavior issues encountered.  My background is to do this type of thing in a script, and control it row by row --- its fantastic to see what you can do with a query though.  Thanks again spencer, much appreciated!

Comment: @spencer7593  Just out of curiosity, what databases support the type of analytic functions you were referring to?

Comment: @JasonB: Oracle 11gR2 and SQL Server 2008r2 are the two databases that I'm familiar with; the MySQL query (above) is emulating the `ROW_NUMBER` function. **ref:** [**Oracle ROW_NUMBER function**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions156.htm#i86310) **ref:** [**SQL Server ROW_NUMBER function**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734(v=sql.105).aspx)